# Footer should adjust to screen size

Tags: html

I did not find a better title to explain my problem. 
I would like to have a footer, which is constantly at the bottom of the page, (5 px space from the bottom). When the window is made smaller, it should also move. My css so far is:

```
#footer {
    height:40px;
    width: 1024px;
    background:#FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Like this it is below the last `div` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/Mh9dT/)

```
 #footer {
        height:40px;
        position:fixed;
        width: 1024px;
        background:#FFF;
        padding: 5px;
        clear: both;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**   [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HrcA/)

```
#footer
{
 position:fixed;
 height:40px;
 background-color:red;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  CSS `Position` property `Fixed`

**CSS**:

```
#footer {
    height:40px;
    width: 1024px;
    background:#FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
    position:fixed;
}
```